# Appending nil to slice results in 0 value

Tags: go

Appending a nil value to a slice of interfaces results in a slice holding a 0 value. [0]

```
var values []interface{}

values = append(values, nil)
```

However doing this,

```
values[0] = nil
```

does what I expected. It results in a slice holding a nil value

```
[<nil>]
```

I need the nil value to pass to my db driver. What is going on here?

Comment: Do you need to update your Go version?  I ran the following in the Go Playground and it works how you would expect: http://play.golang.org/p/Fyl-dLX5aG  Output:[<nil> <nil> <nil>]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue: `append(values, nil)` properly appends a nil wrapped as an interface:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
     var values []interface{}
     values = append(values, nil)
     fmt.Printf("%#v", values) // == []interface {}{interface {}(nil)}
}
```

See [http://play.golang.org/p/*-unk6Hdt*](http://play.golang.org/p/_-unk6Hdt_)

Comment: Sorry. It looks like the 0 was being added somewhere else in my code in a section that I thought I'd commented out.